# Multiple forms to get work

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to insert into the same page a login form and registration form. I tried to do the following:

```
..
<body>
<form runat="server">
..
    <div id="login">
        some inputs and validations
        <asp:button .. />
    </div>
..
    <div id="register">
        some inputs and validations
        <asp:button .. />
    </div>
..
</form>
</body>
```

As you understand, a `form` tag wraps the whole code inside the body (WebForms' concept). each 'form' (login and registration) includes validations (client side & server side). when I click any button, of course, it sends the **two 'forms'** but not before the validation controls validate all the fields (in the two forms).

My goal is to separate them absolutely. I thought about not wrap all the code with `form` tag and include two `form` tag, for each form, but it break the 'rule' and the concept of WebForms, I guess. In addition, as I understood, I cannot include two forms with `runat=server`. What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to have two forms on one page, just forget about the form tag being a form, its just a container in asp.net webforms.

Put your login "form" on the page, and put your register "form" on the page. Thats fine they will ignore each other, all you have to use is the `ValidationGroup` property. Set one validation group for the login bits, set another for the register bits. Also if you want to hive them off a bit futher you can put them in `<asp:Panel>` containers which will let you set a `DefaultButton` parameter, so when you press enter it submits the right "form".

When I first started with asp.net i kept thinking oh what if I need to do... or... but it doesn't come up. You just think of them as being two objects on the same surface.

Because the webforms system maintains state between postbacks you can just work on them like you would a desktop app.

Having said all that, it sounds like you might be just starting out and if you have the choice then go with MVC instead of WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're fighting the validation. Add a validation group to both the controls to be validated and the buttons, like this:

```
<div id="login">
    <asp:TextBox ValidationGroup="Login" ... />
    <asp:Button ValidationGroup="Login" ... />
</div>
```

and of course, a `ValidationGroup` needs to be identified for the `register` form too.